# Xcode 4.3 Passing Variables between Views

Tags: xcode, variables

Xcode 4.3 Storyboard query

Hi, I'm relatively new to Xcode and am completely confused by the variety of solutions to this innocuous question, none of which are working for me in a Storyboard setup. In most non Obj C languages this is a three line solution.

If I have variable X in view A how do I pass X to view B intact?

Could someone point me to robust solution for a limited number of variables in Xcode 4.3 using Storyboards.

I have another similar query at the other end of the spectrum where I need to pass several hundreds of pieces of data to other views. Do I write then to a temp file...

TIA

Comment: Don't let the fact that you are using storyboards confuse you.   You still create a property for the value you want to set in view B and then set that value from view A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HY, You need implement in the sender view controller the:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
 //...//
}
```

function, and you can pass the data in the function body like:

```
(ImageController *)( segue.destinationViewController).property=passed_data;
```

Comment: in this example the function is in the ViewController A, variable X is the passed_data, and property is the secondViewControllers variable (property) where you want store the passed_data. (if you have paired the storyboard items with the controller code file, this will work fine)

Comment: Cheers I'll give that a go tomorrow. Many thanks for such immediate responses.

Comment: In my instance it doesn't like my function body:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"])
    {
        (ImageController *)( segue.myViewController).property=myString;
    }
}

I have put an import on the destination VC. Any ideas?

Comment: i think the problem is: (ImageController *)( segue.myViewController) what you need is (myViewController *)(segue.destinationViewController).Property_Name = myString; (Property_Name is your property in myViewController of course)

Comment: Did this help? If this was the solution please mark answered.

Comment: Apologies for delay but I'm workign on this bit of the code this evening.

Comment: I feel I'm being monumentally thick as it's not sinking in. My line effectively reads:

(FirstVC *)(seque.SecondVC).transfername = inputname.text; 

Currently I'm getting a error ^ against the SecondVC name? It's .h is imported at the start of the file. Do I need to declare it in any way?

Comment: the segue don't have a member named SecondVC. the segue only know the destinationViewController. If i understand right, than your prepareForSegue method is inside the FirstVC and you want pass the data (what is in the inputname variable which have a text propery) to the SecondVC. In this case you need: ((SecondVC *)(seque.destinationViewController)).transfername = inputname.text; If this don't help, please copy more code.

Comment: What I meant was FirstVC = CurrentVC and SecondVC = DesitinationVC

Are you saying use:
((CurrentVC *)(seque.DestinationVC)).transfername = inputname.text;

Where transfername is the segue identifier. 
I have this code in current.

How does destination know what to call the incoming data or is approach to give it an identical name.

Many thanks for your patience. I am completely baffled at such a simple task is so cumbersome. In a lot of languages this task could be accomplished in three lines. Apologies for my frustration. Your help is REALLY appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that i actually understand your problem... you write this code to the FirstVC.m file. Transfername is not the segue identifier, it's your property in the SecondVC. And you can find the datas in your local variable in SecondVC after SecondVC started.o

Comment: So the code what you need is:
((SecondVC *)(seque.destinationVewCcontroller)).transfername = inputname.text
Here first you cast the destinationViewController to SecondVC, that is how the compiler know what kind of Controller is the DestinationVC.
After this cast you can access directly to the variables (propertys) in the SecondVC. So if you have an NSString* transfername property in SecondVC than you can just set the value like i showd you before. You don't need the segue identifier here. That is needed when u want add a target for example to a UIButton, and you can't do that in Storyboard.

Comment: I've got this working, many thanks for your patience. The thing that finally sunk in is that in Obj C++ you pass a data object between the views rather than the raw data and essentially you're packaging up the DO and unpacking it at the receiver.