# Shared class operations in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two viewcontrollers Viewcontroller1 and viewcontroller2
i have to declare a variable globally and use it in both views, however i have to take the value of the variable in view 1, into view2

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shared class and declare the variable in that
then you can import sharedClass.h in both viewcontroller1 and 2 and use it

Sharedclass *shrdclass;

NB: you can also pass the value of a variable to one view to another view without using a sharedclass so easily,check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574163/xcode-4-3-passing-variables-between-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it inside the `AppDelegate` Class or can make the Singlton Instance so that this innstacnec can be persist throught the App lifeCycvle.

Here is the way how can you do the same.

1)declare the instrance in `AppDelegate.h`
Accesss it in `ViewController1` and ViewController2`Just Import that`AppDelegate Header` in these ViewController.

2)second Way Create the Singleton Object

```
 @interface SomeManager : NSObject
   + (KTMySingleton *)sharedManager;
 @end

 static KTMySingleton* _mySharedManager;
 @implementation SomeManager
 + (KTMySingleton*)sharedManager
 {
@synchronized(self) {   
  if(_mySharedManager==nil){
  NSLog(@"Shared Object is Created");
      [[self alloc] init];
  _sharedManager.purchasableProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];               

 }
    return _sharedManager ;
 }
//Here you can use this `purchaseableProducts` throughout the App in any class just calling the `sharedManager` Method.
```

[here is the Link at where you can know how to create the Singlgton Class and object](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)